# Extract with Specific Prefix and control no. of digits in Regex- R

Tags: regex, r

I need to extract the below pattern in R

```
 (10 digits), prefix with 3, 5, 9 (e.g. 3234567890, 5234567890, 9234567890) 
 (10 digits), prefix with 4 (e.g. 4234567890)
 (10 digits), prefix with 8 (e.g. 8234567890)
```

and the below

```
 TAM(5 digits) – e.g. TAM12345 (numbers starting with TAM and 5 digits)
 E(7 digits) – e.g. E1234567 (numbers starting with E and only 7 digits)
 A(5 digits) – e.g. A12345 (numbers starting with A and only 5 digits)
```

I use stingr library.

I am able to extract numbers (with alpha)- not sure how to give specific Prefix and to restrict the digits

The email is below

```
These are the notice number - with high priority
3234567890 and 5234567890 and the long pending issue 9234567890 along with the discuused numbers 4234567890,8234567890.
Special messages from TAM12345,E1234567 and A12345
```

Required Output

```
3234567890, 5234567890, 9234567890
4234567890
8234567890
TAM12345
E1234567
A12345
```

Comment: @Mr.Flick i use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package in R.I am trying find how to get the same through this function

Comment: It would be more helpful to give a character vector of sample input along with the desired output. Because `str_extract_all` accepts regular expressions as the pattern parameter.

Comment: @Prasanna Nandakumar.  Is there a space between characters and numbers for example `discuused numbers4234567890`?

Comment: Edited the question, there is a space between charcaters and numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below code which uses word boundary `\b`. Word boundary is used to match between a word character and a non-word character.

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(x, perl('\\b(?:[35948]\\d{9}|TAM\\d{5}|E\\d{7}|A\\d{5})\\b'))
[[1]]
[1] "3234567890" "5234567890" "9234567890" "4234567890" "8234567890"
[6] "TAM12345"   "E1234567"   "A12345"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `stringr` library:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(x, perl('\\b(?:[3-589]\\d{9}|(?:TAM|A)\\d{5}|E\\d{7})\\b'))
[[1]]
[1] "3234567890" "5234567890" "9234567890" "4234567890" "8234567890"
[6] "TAM12345"   "E1234567"   "A12345"
```

Using the `gsubfn` library:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapply(x, '\\b([3-589]\\d{9}|(?:TAM|A)\\d{5}|E\\d{7})\\b', perl=T)
[[1]]
[1] "3234567890" "5234567890" "9234567890" "4234567890" "8234567890"
[6] "TAM12345"   "E1234567"   "A12345"
```

And base R which handles this just as well.

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\b(?:[3-589]\\d{9}|(?:TAM|A)\\d{5}|E\\d{7})\\b', x, perl=T))
[[1]]
[1] "3234567890" "5234567890" "9234567890" "4234567890" "8234567890"
[6] "TAM12345"   "E1234567"   "A12345"
```

Comment: Note that without the `\b` in the regular expression, something like `str_extract_all("A1234545453453465645", "([34589]\\d{9}|TAM\\d{5}|E\\d{7}|A\\d{5})")` will return two matches. Not sure if that's really the desired behavior.

Comment: @MrFlick wasn't sure of what OP neccessarily wanted, but updated and thanks.