# Extraction of the two digits before comma from numeric column vector

Tags: r, digits

I have a simulated price series being a column vector. From this, I need to extract my two digits in front of the comma with no rounding, i.e. 87 from the price 1,287.85 and 34 from the price 234.13 and store these in yet another column vector.

Example

```
str1 <- c("1,287.85", "234.13")
```

Desired output

```
str2 <- c("87", "34")
```

Comment: Welcome Joakim. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Search and research you are doing a Masters! Its good to show what you have tried so far. take a look at regex answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469442/extract-with-specific-prefix-and-control-no-of-digits-in-regex-r) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899995/r-regex-how-to-extract-string-with-one-or-two-digit-number-within-title). i.e. search R regex digits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(str1, "\\d{2}(?=\\.)"))
#[1] 87 34
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("1,287.85", "234.13")
```

Comment: Amazing method that exactly fulfilled my needs. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ akrun. Apologies. I'm new in this forum. Just to improve your solution, it took me quite a while to realize that NA appears whenever the price by incidence hits an integer, i.e. 198.00 since this is stored as 198 whereby there is no comma to search for. I solved this by simply adding 0.00001 to my entire vector of prices which now works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the `as.integer(yournumber)` to remove the decimal parts and then use the modulo 100 operation:

```
a = 1287.54

as.integer(a) %% 100

#[1] 87
```